# dojo grid with textbox validation

Tags: dojo

I have a dojo enhancedgrid with textbox and other read only attributes. If the item is selected, the textbox value should not be empty before submitting the button. I am not able to validate that specific textbox value as it is not part of attributes. Can anyone let me know how I can get the specific textbox value and ensure that it is not empty before submitting.
Also how can we give a unique name to each texxbox to be able to retrieve the value on server side? Thanks in advance